# Which methods are called only if I press the Home Button?

Tags: android

Is there a method (like onDestroy() or onPause() for example) that is only called if I press the Home Button on my device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you press the Home button on the device, the onPause method will be called. If the device thinks that it needs more memory it might call onStop to let your application shut down. The device can restart your application later from a stopped state. If your process killed, onDestroy will be called.

http://www.androidside.com/data/geditor/0812/1062731775_4e7c4d93_android+activity+life+cycle.jpg

Comment: what about if i'm in widget context and not an activity?